# Problem with attaching of internet gateway - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have problems with assigning two internet gateways in the infrastructure with terraform.
I have two subnets, a subnet manages all the frontend and the other subnets manages all the backend, i want to assign them an internet gateway to each ec2 instance so to can use them from the internet, but I'm getting the next error:

> error attaching EC2 Internet Gateway (igw-0b0af7a9d5274c29d) to VPC (vpc-095fd5e0ee29b981d): InvalidParameterValue: Network vpc-095fd5e0ee29b981d already has an internet gateway attached

Comment: You can not attach an Internet Gateway to an EC2 instance. Internet Gateways are attached to the VPCs. The error says that your VPC does already has an internet gateway, so you would want to set up your route tables correctly, if your instances do not have internet. For the backend subnet, you would want to attach a NAT gateway, assuming the subnet is private.

Comment: what should i specify in my route tables ? the internet gateway id ? @ErvinSzilagyi

Comment: Please provide some more context when you asking something. Route tables require target/destination pairs. You can have many of these depending on your infrastructure. If the destination is the internet gateway, then you put the ID of the internet gateway there. Please read the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html

Comment: i just want expose all my instances to the internet with internet gateway, the problem is, that i think the vpc accept only one internet gateway and i want several internet gateways to expose them to the internet @ErvinSzilagyi

Comment: You only need **one** Internet gateway for your VPC. You then create a route to that gateway in each VPC subnet, which will give **everything** in that subnet an Internet connection. You **do not** need an Internet Gateway for each EC2 instance. That is not at all how Internet Gateways work. What you are doing is like trying to get a new cable modem and router installed in your house for each laptop you own.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to attach more than one InternetGateway per VPC. For ec2 instances to access the internet, add rote to your subnet's route table that directs all default traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to your InternetGateway. Also assign Public IP / Elastic IP to each of EC2.

Refer this AWS doc for more info:-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html